# Why am I getting those pgfkeys errors?

Tags: pgfplots, errors

Suddenly, most of the figures don't appear in the document and the first error is

```
! package pgfkeys error: choice '1.8' unknown in key '/pgfplots/compat/anchors'
```

Another error:

```
! package pgfkeys error: choice '1.8' unknown in key '/pgfplots/compat/labels'
```

Another one:

```
! package pgfkeys error: choice '1.8' unknown in key '/pgfplots/compat/empty line'
```

What is the problem? I am using Texnic Center on Windows, Here is the full code

```
\documentclass{ecsminithesis}  % Use the minithesis Style
\graphicspath{{F:\PhD\Latex}}   % Location of your graphics files
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[square,compress]{natbib}            % Use Natbib style for the refs.
%% \removecolourlinks    % Uncomment this command to remove colour from any links

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs}         %to use \toprule and \bottomrule without error message
\usepackage{pgfplots}         %to plot figure
\usepackage{threeparttable}  
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs}         %to use \toprule and \bottomrule without error message
\usepackage{pgfplots}   
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepackage{subfigure}        % to add subfigures
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}  %to prevent word breaking
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\newcommand*{\head}[1]{\textbf{#1}}%  to make heads of table in BOLD, it is used with booktabs package and \head
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{url} \makeatletter \g@addto@macro{\UrlBreaks}{\UrlOrds} \makeatother
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\input{Definitions}            % Include your abbreviations
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------


\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\title      {Assessment of the Effectiveness of Fuel Cells as an Alternative Technology for Marine Propulsion Systems}
\authors    {\texorpdfstring
             {\href{mailto:ab2e12@soton.ac.uk}{Ameen Bassam}}
             {Ameen Bassam}
            }
\department  {Engineering and the Environment}
\group       {Fluid Structure Interactions}
\addresses  {\groupname\\\deptname\\\univname}
\date       {\today}
\subject    {}
\keywords   {}
%\supervisor {Mr Beavis}
%\examiner   {Dr Butthead}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listoftables

%% -----------------------
%% lstpatch.sty
%% -----------------------
%% lstpatch cannot be distributed with these files. I believe it is only needed if the
%% \lstlistoflistings is used. So this has been turned off by default. Re-add if required:
%% \usepackage{lstpatch}
%% \lstlistoflistings
%% You will need to download lstpatch, possibly from:
%% http://web.mit.edu/texsrc/source/latex/listings/lstpatch.sty
%% -----------------------



%\acknowledgements{Thanks to no one.}
\include{Nomenclature}
\mainmatter
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\include{Introduction}
\include{Chapter2}
\include{Chapter3}
\include{Chapter4}
\include{Chapter5}
\include{Conclusions}
\include{Future}
\appendix
\include{AppendixI}
\backmatter
\bibliography{references}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\end{document}
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Hard to say without full code.

Comment: This error message indicates that your version of `pgfplots` is older than 1.8 . Can you please take a look into your `.log` file and search for the `pgfplots` version? It should be one of the first log entries with the keyword "pgfplots". 
What happens if you write "compat=1.3" (as an experiment, not as real solution as this might change your document)?

Comment: I found this line in my log file : 
Package: pgfplots 2011/07/29 v1.5 (git show 1.5-1-gcc2f2d2 )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error message indicates that your version of pgfplots is older than 1.8 . According to your investigation, it is 1.5.1 .

That means you have two options:

1. upgrade pgfplots. The current stable is 1.12.1 at the time of this writing.
2. change your files to contain `compat=1.5`. This might result in slightly different outcome compared to your old results with `compat=1.8` and `pgfplots 1.8`, but should typically be fine.

I suggest to upgrade `pgfplots` using your TeX package manager.

Comment: How to do so on windows ? i am using TexnicCenter

Comment: On windows, you are probably using MikTeX (TexnicCenter is just the editor, the actual TeX system is MikTeX). MikTeX is a TeX package manager and supports automatic updates of all or selected packages. Try googling for "MikTeX update". If you do not find MikTeX on your system, you might have a TeX Live system (but that is unlikely on windows). TeX Live would also allow package upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already mentioned, you should update this package.
In the terminal you can run the following commands (It can take a few minutes):

```
$ sudo tlmgr update --self
$ sudo tlmgr update pgfplots
```

Comment: Is it not possible to update without tlmgr?