# pgfplots: how to nest and scale axis environments

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to generate a more complex figure by tikz. But it has some bugs. I don't know why. The code is as follows:

```
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,environ}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[!tp]

\begin{minipage}{.49\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel style={align=center},
    xlabel=$Expiration\ Time\ (s)$ \\(a),
    ylabel style={align=center},
    ylabel=$Reduced\ RTT\ Ratio\ (\%)$,
    xmin=10, xmax=60,
    ymin=75, ymax=95,
    legend style={nodes=right},
    legend pos= south east]
\addplot table {delay.txt};
\addlegendentry{10000}
\end{axis}
\draw(0.1,0.1) node{ 
\begin{axis}[scale=0.2][
    xlabel style={align=center},
    xlabel=$Expiration\ Time\ (s)$ \\(b),
    xlabel style={align=center},
    ylabel=$Cache\ Hit\ Rate\ (\%)$,
    xmin=10, xmax=60,
    ymin=80, ymax=100,
    legend style={nodes=right},
    legend pos= south east]
\addplot table {hit.txt};
\addlegendentry{10000}
\end{axis}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Effects of expiration time of cache entry in delegates \newline}
\label{figure 4}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Date, i.e., delay.txt and hit.txt are as following：

```
delay.txt:
    10  83.70616734
    20  87.78888284
    30  89.30183444
    40  90.08903274
    50  90.58099978
    60  90.92872104

hit.txt:
    10  90.98347396
    20  95.0861077
    30  96.60898943
    40  97.3979899
    50  97.89094057   
    60  98.23992643
```

I think there exist some bugs in the following code, but I don't know why!

```
   [xlabel style={align=center},
    xlabel=$Expiration\ Time\ (s)$ \\(b),
    xlabel style={align=center},
    ylabel=$Cache\ Hit\ Rate\ (\%)$,
    xmin=10, xmax=60,
    ymin=80, ymax=100,
    legend style={nodes=right},
    legend pos= south east]
```

The result most like:

[image]

**Can you help me? Thank you!**

Comment: Please make your example compilable (`\documentclass` is missing) and explain what is the problem here. Why do you think there are some bugs? Erros, warnings, crashes...?

Comment: A couple of unrelated comments: i) `$Expiration\ Time\ (s)$` is not math but text, so don't use math mode: `Expiration Time (s)`. Same for the `ylabel`. If you want italic, use `\textit{...}`,  or add `font=\itshape` to the `xlabel style`.  ii) You generally don't want to have the `pdftex` option for `graphicx`, so just use `\usepackage{graphicx}`. The package figures that one out by itself.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I am a new learner. I will pay attention to the specifications. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution using `\savebox` to avoid peculiar interferences arising from nesting and scaling; this also allows us to position the inserted `axis` in the scope of the outer `axis` with `axis cs` coordinates. Note that for asymmetric scaling (rectangular plots) we cannot use `xscale` and `yscale` as offered by `tikz`, since label positions don't end up where one would expect. Instead, we use `unit vector ratio` and then do symmetric canvas scaling (= scaling including also the text).

A sketch of the construction:

```
% First construct the graph to be inserted and save it
\newsavebox\insertedgraph
\savebox\insertedgraph
  {\begin{tikzpicture}
     \begin{axis}[unit vector ratio=..., xmin=..., xmax=...]
     ...
     \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}%
  }

% Now for the main graph
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
  ... \addplot ... whatever ...
  % Now we insert the other graph at a reduced size
  \node at (axis cs: ...position ...)
    {\scalebox{... scaling factor ...}{\usebox\insertedgraph}};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Here are two examples: a simple one with plots defined by expressions, and the example of the original post reading the data from tables.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\newsavebox\insertedgraph
\savebox\insertedgraph
  {\begin{tikzpicture}
     \begin{axis}[unit vector ratio=1 2,xmin=0,xmax=5]
       \addplot[domain=0.1:5] {1/x};
     \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[domain=-5:5] {x^2};
    \node at (axis cs:-0.2,15) {\scalebox{0.5}{\usebox\insertedgraph}};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\begin{filecontents}{delay.txt}
    10  83.70616734
    20  87.78888284
    30  89.30183444
    40  90.08903274
    50  90.58099978
    60  90.92872104
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{hit.txt}
    10  90.98347396
    20  95.0861077
    30  96.60898943
    40  97.3979899
    50  97.89094057   
    60  98.23992643
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\newsavebox\mybox
\savebox\mybox
  {\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    unit vector ratio=3 2,
    xlabel style={align=center},
    xlabel=Expiration Time (s)\\(b),
    xlabel style={align=center},
    ylabel=Cache\ Hit Rate (\%),
    xmin=10, xmax=60,
    ymin=80, ymax=100,
    legend style={nodes=right},
    legend pos= south east]
    \addplot table {hit.txt};
    \addlegendentry{10000}
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel style={align=center},
    xlabel=Expiration Time (s)\\(a),
    ylabel style={align=center},
    ylabel=Reduced RTT Ratio\ (\%),
    xmin=10, xmax=60,
    ymin=75, ymax=95,
    legend style={nodes=right},
    legend pos= south east]
\addplot table {delay.txt};
\addlegendentry{10000}
\node at (axis cs:35,81) {\scalebox{0.4}{\usebox\mybox}}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you are very patient! What you show is also work in my computer. But when there is a input from .txt, it doesn't work. Maybe I place the input '\addplot table {delay.txt};' in a wrong place? I placed it after '\mypic{}' and before '{\usebox\mybox};'.  Maybe it can work for a formula, but not to a input from XXX.txt document?

Comment: @Sean Good point. I have now added your original example. It also works for input from files :-)

Comment: @Sean I have rewritten and simplified the description of the solution. If you find that it works, consider ticking my second answer instead of the first one. I think it is the more robust one.

Comment: Thank you! The picture you show is what I want! But there is a error in my computer, i.e., ! Package pgfkeys Error: Choice '1.14' unknown in key '/pgfplots/compat/anchors' . I searched it in the network. It shows that maybe the pgfplots version is old. [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244956/why-am-i-getting-those-pgfkeys-errors) But the .log shows 'Package: pgfplots 2011/12/29 v1.5.1 (git show 1.5.1-4-g53e640f )'. The version is v1.5.1, and higher than v1.14. I have no idea what's wrong?

Comment: @Sean Remove `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}` and see if you get the same picture as above. This command just indicates that this picture works with version 1.14. If you compile the document with a later version of pgfplots, it will switch back to this version such that the document still works even if some features have changed. But it may well be that your version of pgfplots is sufficient. If the picture comes out differently or you get other error messages with the code above, than you should upgrade your pgfplots (which is no bad idea anyway, it is quite old).

Comment: I upgrade the pgfplots, and it works! Thank you very much!

Comment: I have set the second answer as the best solution to this problem.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is in the line `\begin{axis}[scale=0.2][` (apart from the missing `\documentclass`).

First, the `axis` environment has only one set of options, so you have to replace `][` by `,`.

Second, `scale` transforms only the drawing, not the labels etc. Therefore use `transform canvas={scale=0.2}` instead.

With

```
\begin{axis}[transform canvas={scale=0.2},
```

instead of

```
\begin{axis}[scale=0.2][
```

you get

[image]

Comment: I would also suggest not adding the small `axis` inside a `node`, instead use `at={(x,y)}` in the `axis` options`.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! It's really what I want! I have another question. How can I change the shape of the embedded (small) picture?  I.e., it is a square at this moment, how can I change it to be rectangular? While the larger picture is still keep as a square.

Comment: @Sean See the discussion on [Rectangular graphs in pgfplots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246455). If you just want to have asymmetric scaling, you can replace `scale=0.2` by `xscale=0.2,yscale=0.3`, but this will distort letters. Or you use scaling outside of `transform canvas`, then the graphical elements will be stretched, but the letters remain the same. Try e.g. `xscale=1.5` as an additional option of `axis`.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I have tried the second method. The letters is not change (I also tried the first method you teach me, the letters have distorted). But there still exist a problem, i.e., the _xlable_ is on the right side, not the middle. Even if I have use 'xlabel style={align=center}' . (The first method doesn't change the position of xlable. The xlable keep in the middle.) Can you help me? Thank you!

Comment: @Sean There seems to be a problem in the interaction of label positioning with scaling. Try the option `unit vector ratio=...` with a value different from `1 1` together with canvas scaling. For an example of this option, see [this answer to "Rectangular graphs in pgfplots"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/246527/110998).

Comment: Thank you! I think your your judgment is right! Because if I set yscale=2, the ylable will also change the position. But when I try the method you told me, it seems no change. I add 'unit vector ratio=1 2,' but the xlable still in the right side. When I set 'unit vector ratio=1 20,' it seems the xlable is in the middle, but a part of the small (inserted) picture has moved out of the big picture.

Comment: @gernot Thank you! I think your your judgment is right! Because if I set yscale=2, the ylable will also change the position. But when I try the method you told me, it seems no change. I add 'unit vector ratio=1 2,' but the xlable still in the right side. When I set 'unit vector ratio=1 20,' it seems the xlable is in the middle, but a part of the small (inserted) picture has moved out of the big picture.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Regarding your suggestion to use the option `at`: It seems that the coordinates are with respect to the transformed cs. This means that the `axis` will shift when changing its scaling factor, as also the `at` anchor will change. Is there any disadvantage of putting `axis` into a node (which then can be positioned according to the unscaled coordinates)?

Comment: In hindsight, I don't actually know if there are any disadvantages to it, so perhaps my comment was unwarranted. It just seemed a bit odd to me.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Your intuition may have been right since it seems that nesting `axis` within a node as strange effects.

Comment: @Sean I don't understand the problem you still have. I have added another solution. Try it, and if something is still wrong, let's discuss the problem below the new solution, with reference to it.